# Error loading JSON data into big query: flat value specified for record field

Tags: json, google-bigquery

We are seeing the following error when loading a JSON record into Big Query via the load command:

> BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'job_d727bf8944884b20b709ded2887b7a13': flat value specified for record field
>   Failure details:
>
> - Unexpected. Please try again.
> - Row larger than the maximum allowed size

The record in question appears to be well under the maximum allowed size for JSON and is well-formed.  The schema for the table uses a nested record, but neither the format of the log nor the schema has recently changed, so it's unclear why this error is suddenly occurring.

**Update**:

We usually run the load operation with a --max_bad_records param so that it will skip the few badly formed records that might exist.  I tried re-loading the file you specified was the source of the failure individually, and it seems to have succeeded this time with no errors, both with and without max_bad_records defined.

```
bq load --max_bad_records 20 --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON telemetry_data_2013_06_20 "gs:/.../2013-06-12-01/ip-10-144-3-198.log"
```

Here are the job ids:

```
job_5822a36c5c364117a6651f3e8b81b49f
job_ed4080f9f60c485bb265c09367902f00
```

Why did this file succeed this time around?

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs we have access to, it looks like there is a repeated entry in your load job that is simply ":", without any additional data.

It's possible that there is an issue in BigQuery that, in some cases, sets the single record size limit to 2 MB rather than the advertised 16MB. Can you confirm that the line that throws the "Row larger than the maximum allowed size" response is under 2Mb?

Comment: FYI we have a support ticket open for this as well, in case you want to coordinate. Google Enterprise Support Case #03215215

Comment: I haven't been able to locate the data error you claim above in the file in question. Can you confirm that the file name and byte offset are correct?